# Bootstraps Modal when element is highlighted

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So here's a screenshot of a working nicely modal:[image]

But whenever I hover or select an element inside the modal form, it acts like this :[image]

It gets the `<embed>` image whenever I highlight a text or select a radio button in the `<form>` modal . Tried some css like z-index and the likes but didn't work. Any help are appreciated.

Comment: It works nicely when there's no embedded video on the background.

Comment: Pretty hard to help with no code

Comment: Can it be a `z-index` problem?